# C# saving an image from PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, gdi, picturebox

i have a code like this:

```
private void Load_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();            
        if (dialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK){
            MessageBox.Show(dialog.FileName,"My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            string s; 
            s=".bmp";
            if (dialog.FileName.Substring(dialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).Equals(s))
            {
                picBox_1.Load(dialog.FileName);
                BitmapFile = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName.ToString());
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a BMP file!");
            }
        }

    }
```

so, load image. and have an error in this:

```
private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        try
        {
            if (picBox_1.Image != null)
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dialog.FileName, "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    string s;
                    s = ".bmp";
                    if (dialog.FileName.Substring(dialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).Equals(s))
                    {

                        picBox_1.Image.Save(dialog.FileName.ToString());
                        //BitmapFile.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a BMP file!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("My PicBox is empty!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Cannot save file, error!"); }

    }
```

this is general GDI error. I suppose, that i can't write to file (not enough rights, maybe). how can i improve this error?

Comment: What is the error you get? And you don't have to suppose anything, just use `catch (Exception saveEx) { MessageBox.Show(saveEx.Message); }`. Doesn't that exception carry an innerexception which could provide more detail?

Comment: You're not trying to overwrite the source file, are you?

Comment: Please aid in clearing up confusion, by _improve this error_, do you mean _correct this error_ as in _make it go away?_ I don't know how anyone can interpret _improve this error_ as _how to see this error_ or _how to improve handling of this error_, but there you are, some are.

Comment: What and where **exactly** is the error?

Comment: i improve, using this in load function:
    `picBox_1.Image=Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);`

Answer (score 1):

you should catch the exceptions properly, not with a MessageBox which tells you nothing about the exact exception thrown!

at minimum your catch block should look like this:

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
  MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

and I say at minimum because you should in fact log the exception somewhere, using a logging framework like NLog or Log4Net and dump stack trace and other details. You are not even able to tell the excact type of Exception if you show a message with a static string and not the details of the actual exception.

Comment: _'this is general GDI error._' Which seems the user _is_ aware of the exception, just that a Generic GDI+ Error, is, well, awfully generic and the exception isn't in question here.

Comment: what? what does it mean? how was this explained in the question?

Comment: That's the point, this error can mean any number of things (invalid access rights, locked files, out of memory and so on.) The words _'improve this error'_ can be replaced with _'correct this error'_, I think.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment instead of voting down everybody, consider that question was not reach of details and general GDI error as mentioned in the question could be anything, it is not said it's the exception type. my answer and other answers are suggesting ways to handle exceptions properly, better than in current code, not deserved down vote for assumptions on a question not well written.

Comment: No, if you have experience with GDI+ and someone tells you a _general GDI error_ then that translates to a _Generic GDI+ Error_ (that IS the error, in its entirety) , which is _all the information you get_. They deserve down-votes because they don't properly answer the question, but go tangentially on about how to see the error, not fix it.

Comment: then give an answer yourself if you are so skilled in GDI and not downvote all the others who are spending time suggesting better exception handling which anyway is always a good practice, does not solve his issue here but still is a valid suggestion.

Comment: Don't take it to heart, this is how the system works - the answer is a valid _suggestion_ but without content that actually _answers_ the question, it's a candidate for a comment and not a real answer; I'm not _'so skilled in GDI'_, though. And I would give an answer once I have gleaned sufficient information, such as a reply to my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should only catch specific exceptions that you intend to handle or recover from, and log the details. Never catch `Exception` as you would potentially be masking bigger issues with your server if they occur.

Unexpected exceptions should bubble up so that the cause can quickly be identified when they occur.

See here for [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).

Comment: Yes, see my comments on other answers - this isn't the topic at hand and doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Well we'll have to disagree on that, your obviously expecting a lot of GDI errors in your app.

Comment: Really this should have been a comment as it doesn't *directly* address the issue.

Comment: The issue being? How to improve error handling? `how can I improve this error?`

Comment: @TheCodeKing How, exactly, do you _improve_ an error? And _error_ != _error handling_: the two are separate issues. The only way to _improve the error itself_ is to remove the error. If you _improve alerting of errors_ you haven't improved the error, have you?

Comment: You didn't specify `error message` or `error handling`, you just said `errors`, which is ambiguous. It would be remiss not to point out the glaring bad practice in the code to help you improve the "errors", and this in turn has an impact on your error messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You're eating the exception and losing all the juicy detail. Try changing your `catch` block to something like this to see what's going on:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString(), "Error Saving Image", MessageBoxIcons.Error);
}
```

Also, consider implementing some logging (to the event viewer and/or text file. This will allow you to have a simple message box, but with all the juicy detail put somewhere useful to fetch after the event.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error Saving Image", MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    // _logger is a private field on this class in this case.
    _logger.Log(ex, string.Format("Saving image to {0}", dialog.Filename))
}
```

You could look at [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) amongst other things for the actual logging, but at the very least write a class to [write exception detail to the event viewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024).

Comment: _'this is general GDI error._' Which seems the user _is_ aware of the exception, just that a Generic GDI+ Error, is, well, awfully generic and the exception isn't in question here.